# overwrite default properties in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

could someone explain overwriting default properties and even extending them with jQuery inside my plugin example and also the closure function

```
$.fn.myObject = function(overwriteProperties) {
    var properties = {myproperty1: "defaultvalue"}
    // overwrite properties here
    function doStuffHere() {

    }
    return (function() {
        return this; // does this part here refer to the object of myDiv
    });
} 
$('#myDiv').myObject({myPoperty1:"newValue"});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`extend`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend) to overwrite the default options:

```
var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

Also see:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: still would like a demonstration especially with the expty object in the extend function

Comment: @littleMan have a look at http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-set-default-settings-in-your.html

Comment: var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
This way, if the options object is null or undefined, an empty object is used and therefore no properties are overwritten.